# How do I implement mouse click in Awesomium?

Tags: c#, awesomium

I wrote this code to test the Inject mouse method but it is not working for me. The test is supposed to click in the google text box search area, but the box never gets highlighted. Any idea why?

Google's page does load. The code runs (confirmed through break points), but nothing happens.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private IWebView webView;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            initiate();

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
            click(650, 405);
        }

        private async void initiate()
        {

            WebSession session = WebCore.CreateWebSession(
@"C:\SessionDataPath", WebPreferences.Default);
            webView = WebCore.CreateWebView(
      this.ClientSize.Width,
      this.ClientSize.Height, session, WebViewType.Window
     );
            webView.ParentWindow = this.Handle;
            webView.Source = new Uri("http://www.google.com");
            await Task.Delay(30000);
            click(650, 405);

        }

        public void click(int x, int y)
        {
            webView.InjectMouseMove(x, y);
            webView.InjectMouseDown(MouseButton.Left);
            webView.InjectMouseUp(MouseButton.Left);
        }
    }
```

I tried to get this code to work with chromium handle by looking at the proper chromium class but it didn't work

```
  private async Task<bool> clickCoorindate(Point point)
        {
            webView.FocusView();
            int x = point.X; // X coordinate of the click
            int y = point.Y; // Y coordinate of the click
            IntPtr handle = webView.ProcessHandle;
            StringBuilder className = new StringBuilder(100);
            while (className.ToString() != "Chrome_RenderWidgetHostHWND") // The class control for the browser
            {
                handle = GetWindow(handle, 5); // Get a handle to the child window
                GetClassName(handle, className, className.Capacity);
                if (className.ToString() == "Chrome_RenderWidgetHostHWND")
                    handle = Handle;

            }

            IntPtr lParam = (IntPtr)((y << 16) | x); // The coordinates
            IntPtr wParam = IntPtr.Zero; // Additional parameters for the click (e.g. Ctrl)
            const uint downCode = 0x201; // Left click down code
            const uint upCode = 0x202; // Left click up code
            const uint moveCode = 0x200;

            SendMessage(handle, downCode, wParam, lParam); // Mouse button down
            SendMessage(handle, upCode, wParam, lParam); // Mouse button up
            Thread.Sleep(20);
            SendMessage(handle, downCode, wParam, lParam); // Mouse button down
            SendMessage(handle, upCode, wParam, lParam); // Mouse button up

            return true;

        }
```

Comment: are you sure you click on the right coordinate?
I'd add a javascript click event on your page and write on the javascript console whenever that event happens (and which coordinate)

you can use awesomium inspector to read the console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the documentation (see: *[`WebViewType`](http://docs.awesomium.net/?tc=T_Awesomium_Core_WebViewType)*), a *windowed* view captures all input itself and you cannot *inject* input programmatically using Awesomium API (you could do this as you tried, by sending native Windows messages to the appropriate HWND but it's not suggested and straightforward procedure).

To be able to *inject* input programmatically using the *`InjectXXX`* methods, make sure your view is of type ***[offscreen](http://wiki.awesomium.net/general-use/introduction-to-web-views.html)***.

Answer (score 0):

in my XNA game i use a lot Awesomium and this is my InputSystem i've implemented in my awesomium component, it works very well.
note that this is just a part of my class, so some methods aren't here but they are not needed to understand the process
basically in my thread. basically i hook to the messages in my form and relay them to the WebView. Hope this helps

```
  public partial class BasicAwesomiumComponent : DrawableGameComponent {

  private delegate Int32 ProcessMessagesDelegate(Int32 code, Int32 wParam, ref Message lParam);

  private static class User32 {
     [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
     internal static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(Int32 windowsHookId, ProcessMessagesDelegate function, IntPtr mod, Int32 threadId);

     [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
     internal static extern Int32 UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hook);

     [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
     internal static extern Int32 CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hook, Int32 code, Int32 wParam, ref Message lParam);

     [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
     internal static extern Boolean TranslateMessage(ref Message message);

     [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
     internal static extern IntPtr FindWindow(String className, String windowName);

     [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
     internal static extern int RegisterWindowMessage(String msg);

     [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
     internal static extern IntPtr SendMessage(HandleRef hWnd, Int32 msg, Int32 wParam, Int32 lParam);

     [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
     internal static extern bool SystemParametersInfo(Int32 nAction, Int32 nParam, ref Int32 value, Int32 ignore);

     [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
     internal static extern int GetSystemMetrics(Int32 nIndex);
  }

  private static class Kernel32 {
     [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
     internal static extern Int32 GetCurrentThreadId();
  }

  private static class SystemMetrics {
     internal static Int32 MouseWheelScrollDelta {
        get {
           return 120;
        }
     }

     internal static Int32 MouseWheelScrollLines {
        get {
           var scrollLines = 0;

           if (User32.GetSystemMetrics(75) == 0) {
              var hwnd = User32.FindWindow("MouseZ", "Magellan MSWHEEL");
              if (hwnd != IntPtr.Zero) {
                 var windowMessage = User32.RegisterWindowMessage("MSH_SCROLL_LINES_MSG");
                 scrollLines = (Int32)User32.SendMessage(new HandleRef(null, hwnd), windowMessage, 0, 0);
                 if (scrollLines != 0) {
                    return scrollLines;
                 }
              }
              return 3;
           }
           User32.SystemParametersInfo(104, 0, ref scrollLines, 0);
           return scrollLines;
        }
     }
  }

  private enum WindowsMessage {
     KeyDown = 0x0100,
     KeyUp = 0x0101,
     Char = 0x0102,

     MouseMove = 0x0200,
     LeftButtonDown = 0x0201,
     LeftButtonUp = 0x0202,
     LeftButtonDoubleClick = 0x0203,

     RightButtonDown = 0x0204,
     RightButtonUp = 0x0205,
     RightButtonDoubleClick = 0x0206,

     MiddleButtonDown = 0x0207,
     MiddleButtonUp = 0x0208,
     MiddleButtonDoubleClick = 0x0209,

     MouseWheel = 0x020A,
  }

  private struct Message {
     internal IntPtr HWnd;
     internal Int32 Msg;
     internal IntPtr WParam;
     internal IntPtr LParam;
     internal IntPtr Result;
  }

  private IntPtr hookHandle;
  private ProcessMessagesDelegate processMessages;

  private Int32 ProcessMessages(Int32 code, Int32 wParam, ref Message lParam) {
     if (this.Enabled && code == 0 && wParam == 1) {

        bool processed = false;

        switch ((WindowsMessage)lParam.Msg) {
           case WindowsMessage.KeyDown:
           case WindowsMessage.KeyUp:
           case WindowsMessage.Char:
              WebKeyboardEvent keyboardEvent = new WebKeyboardEvent((uint)lParam.Msg, lParam.WParam, lParam.LParam, 0);

              awesomiumContext.Post(state => {
                 if (!WebView.IsLive) return;
                 WebView.InjectKeyboardEvent(keyboardEvent);
              }, null);

              processed = true;
              break;

           case WindowsMessage.MouseWheel:
              var delta = (((Int32)lParam.WParam) >> 16);
              awesomiumContext.Post(state => {
                 if (!WebView.IsLive) return;
                 WebView.InjectMouseWheel(delta / SystemMetrics.MouseWheelScrollDelta * 16 * SystemMetrics.MouseWheelScrollLines, 0);
              }, null);

              processed = true;
              break;
        }

        if (!processed) {
           WindowsMessage message = (WindowsMessage)lParam.Msg;
           awesomiumContext.Post(state => {
              if (!WebView.IsLive) return;

              switch (message) {
                 case WindowsMessage.MouseMove:
                    var mouse = Mouse.GetState();
                    WebView.InjectMouseMove(mouse.X - area.X, mouse.Y - area.Y);
                    break;

                 case WindowsMessage.LeftButtonDown:
                    WebView.InjectMouseDown(MouseButton.Left);
                    break;
                 case WindowsMessage.LeftButtonUp:
                    WebView.InjectMouseUp(MouseButton.Left);
                    break;
                 case WindowsMessage.LeftButtonDoubleClick:
                    WebView.InjectMouseDown(MouseButton.Left);
                    break;

                 case WindowsMessage.RightButtonDown:
                    WebView.InjectMouseDown(MouseButton.Right);
                    break;
                 case WindowsMessage.RightButtonUp:
                    WebView.InjectMouseUp(MouseButton.Right);
                    break;
                 case WindowsMessage.RightButtonDoubleClick:
                    WebView.InjectMouseDown(MouseButton.Right);
                    break;

                 case WindowsMessage.MiddleButtonDown:
                    WebView.InjectMouseDown(MouseButton.Middle);
                    break;
                 case WindowsMessage.MiddleButtonUp:
                    WebView.InjectMouseUp(MouseButton.Middle);
                    break;
                 case WindowsMessage.MiddleButtonDoubleClick:
                    WebView.InjectMouseDown(MouseButton.Middle);
                    break;
              }
           }, null);
        }
        User32.TranslateMessage(ref lParam);
     }

     return User32.CallNextHookEx(IntPtr.Zero, code, wParam, ref lParam);
  }
}
```

update:
note that in my component, to hook the message pump, i use

```
int currentThread = Kernel32.GetCurrentThreadId();
// Create the message hook.
hookHandle = User32.SetWindowsHookEx(3, ProcessMessages, IntPtr.Zero, currentThread);
```

my surface in an Offscreen webview so the more complex, this should work for you too

Comment: I am aware of this method and I do something like that with the webbrowser control for a Flash game but the Flash is buggy with the webbrowser control so I am trying chromium out. I wasn't able to get it to work with chromium as I wasn't able to get the handle of the view. the code is below.

Comment: read my update

so get current form thread id and set a hook to it

Answer (score 0):

i posted a separated answer to give another direction:
take a look at this gist: https://gist.github.com/robertkhrona/918109

it seems to suggest to do

```
webView.InjectMouseMove(x,y);
webView.InjectMouseDown(MouseButton.Left);
webView.InjectMouseMove(x,y);
webView.InjectMouseUp(MouseButton.Left);
```

so moving (to the same position) between the two mousedown/up event
btw i think this shouldn't be needed tho

which version of awesomium are you running?

update:
Remember to set the focus on your WebView before injecting inputs

```
webView.Focus();
```

Comment: I am using the latest version. Also I saw that post and I tried that and it didn't work. can someone provide me with a sample working code that would click on an area on any website?

Comment: do you need a webview or you can work with the webcontrol?

Comment: I prefer a webview, but I can start with a webcontrol until I learn more about awesomium. Also I would have liked to do an offscreen later, but whatever gets me started then I can move toward that goal. I am trying to automate a flash game

Comment: forget to say "Remember to set the focus on your WebView before injecting inputs". updated

Comment: I had tried that but it didn't make a difference, so I removed it from the code.  Have you been able to try this out with the google page to click in the textbox area?

Answer (score 0):

I set the viewtype to offscreen and the injectclick worked fine, when set to window it doesn't work. I don't know why, but I can work with that.